# Webservice increment variable for id use singleton/synchronize

Tags: java, web-services, design-patterns, singleton, primary-key

I am implementing a webservice witch is used to attack one DB.
i need to generate ID for objects that i store and i don't know what's the best way to do it.
i need to increment a INT.

Obviously the webservice must to be used for so much people and maybe various at same time.

so, what's is a good solution?

singleton/synchronize??

i think is the only way i know, maybe there are others better.

if u can show me one example it will be very appreciated.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronize has horrible overhead. If all you need is an incremental counter, you can use [AtomicLong's incrementAndGet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet%28%29). Put the AtomicLong in a Singleton to have a server-wide access.

**Edit:** Some code example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class AtomicIdGenerator
{
    private static class SingletonHolder
    {
        public static final AtomicIdGenerator instance = new AtomicIdGenerator();
    }

    public static AtomicIdGenerator getInstance()
    {
        return SingletonHolder.instance;
    }

    private AtomicLong mIdGenerator = null;

    private AtomicIdGenerator()
    {
        mIdGenerator = new AtomicLong();
    }

    private AtomicLong getGenerator()
    {
        return mIdGenerator;
    }

    public long getNewId()
    {
        return getGenerator().incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Usage example is simply:

```
long tNewId = AtomicIdGenerator.getInstance().getNewId();
```

This will be thread-safe, and without any overhead from synchronization. If you foresee yourself handling lots of concurrent use cases in the future, the [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package provides lots of battle-proven implementations for your use cases.

Comment: thank you, its working perfectly =)   I dont know what will happend when various clients use it at same time, but i hope it works
THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Use synchronize block to achieve this. In synchronized block only one thread can enter inside it.

JVM guarantees that Java synchronized code will only be executed by one thread at a time.

Comment: i tried first what our partner told me in the other answer, i hope it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. I've done it a while back, it was based on PostgreSql and iBatis, but you can get the idea.

```
public class Sequence implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7526471155622776147L;
    private String name  = null;
    private int nextId = 0;

    public Sequence () {
    }

    public Sequence (String name, int nextId) {
        this.name = name;
        this.nextId = nextId;
    }

    public final String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    public final void setName (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final int getNextId () {
        return nextId;
    }

    public final void setNextId (int nextId) {
        this.nextId = nextId;
    }

}


public class SequenceSqlMapDao extends SqlMapClientDaoSupport implements SequenceDao {

  /**
   * This is a generic sequence ID generator that is based on a database
   * table called 'SEQUENCE', which contains two columns (NAME, NEXTID).
   * <p/>
   * This approach should work with any database.
   *
   * @param name The name of the sequence.
   * @return The Next ID
   * @
   */
  public final synchronized int getNextId(String name) {
    Sequence sequence = new Sequence(name, -1);
    //Sequence sequence = new Sequence();
    sequence = (Sequence) getSqlMapClientTemplate ().queryForObject("getSequence", sequence);
    if (sequence == null) {
            try {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error: SHOOT! A null sequence was returned from the database (could not get next " + name + " sequence).");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SequenceSqlMapDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
    Object parameterObject = new Sequence(name, sequence.getNextId() + 1);
    getSqlMapClientTemplate ().update("updateSequence", parameterObject);
    int nextId = sequence.getNextId();

    parameterObject  = null;
    sequence = null;

    return nextId;
  }

}
```

If nothing else this is pretty database agnostic. You'd still have to expose the method in your webservice.
PS - I forgot where I got this from, otherwise I'd give credit to proper source.